# XSLT keep namespace on output

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I need help preserving the namespace on XSLT transformation. I see other threads have solutions, but I don't understand them. When I use the XSLT transformation below, all the namespace disappears. Below is what I'm trying to accomplish. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Before transform XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Worker
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:this="this.file/eib"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:tv="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.TypedValue">
    <Detail>
        <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
        <PayCode>Earning</PayCode>
        <Amount>4243.20</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
        <PayCode>Deduction</PayCode>
        <Amount>2265.60</Amount>
    </Detail>
</Worker>
```

My XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wd is xsd this env"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Worker>
                <xsl:for-each select="Worker" >
                    <Detail>
                        <EmployeeID><xsl:value-of select="Detail[(PayCode ='Earning')]/EmployeeID"/></EmployeeID>
                        <PayCode><xsl:value-of select="Detail[(PayCode ='Earning')]/PayCode"/></PayCode>
                        <Amount><xsl:value-of select="Detail[(PayCode ='Earning') and (string-length(Amount) > 0)]/Amount"/></Amount>
                    </Detail>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Worker>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worker
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:this="this.file/eib"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:tv="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.TypedValue">
   <Detail>
      <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
      <PayCode>Earning</PayCode>
      <Amount>4243.20</Amount>
   </Detail>
</Worker>
```

Comment: The namespace declarations disappear, because the namespaces are not used in the output. Why do you need to keep them (or think you need to keep them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in *XSLT 2.0* (the version you used), namespaces disappear because you used `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute.

Just remove it and all namespaces included in your XSLT sheet, except for `xsl`, will be presented in the output, in the order of appearance.

But if you decided to omit all namespaces, it is easier to write `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"`, instead of writing them again.

Comment: Thank you! That was simple enough and it worked. As you can see, I'm beginner level.

Comment: @RemoHernandez Note that this preserves the namespaces declared in the stylesheet, not those declared in the input XML.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no good reason to keep namespace declarations that are not used in your output. But if you really want to have them, why don't you simply copy them (as part of their parent element) - for example:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Worker">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Detail[PayCode ='Earning']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worker xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:this="this.file/eib"
        xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
        xmlns:tv="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.TypedValue">
   <Detail>
      <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
      <PayCode>Earning</PayCode>
      <Amount>4243.20</Amount>
   </Detail>
</Worker>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/gVhD8Qt

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked. This was for a Workday integration and the namespace and the output is necessary to print out an excel summary file.